# Safety question about isolating transformer

Tags: transformer, grounding

I have a situation identical to the one linked below and I was wondering what others might think. Electrical professionals have told me two different things and I want go with the safest option.

I have a 120V pool light that's pretty old and I'm replacing with a 12V/35W LED light. A 12V pool-rated isolating safety transformer will be installed back at the equipment pad. The idea is the existing 120V feed from the sub panel goes to the transformer where it is grounded to the transformer's ground bar. Then off the transformer will be two 12V leads, and no ground, going to the light's J box.

That's the typical setup. I'm re-using the existing 12AWG wire from the pad to the pool's junction box (under the diving board) to carry the 12V current. Included in that wire conduit (PVC) is the standard black, white and green ground wires. Should this ground wire be connected, which would be from the pool junction box to the transformer's ground bar (shared by the 120V feed's ground wire), or leave it totally disconnected on both sides since the 12V transformer doesn't require it or diagram it?

Confusing the matter is that, for some reason, the 12V light also has a ground wire included in its cord. Should I be grounding this cord to the junction box at the pool like the 120V light was? Or just cap it and leave it off? If so, what about the situation described in the forum below?

Could a ground fault elsewhere in the house make it to this pool light?

https://forums.mikeholt.com/threads/egc-on-a-12v-pool-light.2553235/

More info. This is the transformer I am using. Also the transformer's 120V feed will be downstream of a GFCI outlet

> Intermatic PX50
> 50 W POOL & SPA SAFETY TRANSFORMER, BEIGE STEEL ENCLOSURE, INPUT 120V, OUTPUT 12,13,14 V
> These safety transformers are specifically designed to supply 12-14 VAC and are suitable for direct connection to underwater pool/spa lights. A grounded shield between the primary and secondary winding assures safe operation. Built-in circuit protection will disconnect power to the transformer in case of an overload.

Picture shows one solution for the grounding of the light and a proposal for what to do with the "old" ground back to the transformer.[image]

Comment: If lightning strikes the grid, what if it exceeds the transformer insulation rating then decide where you want the return lines grounded for arc protection.

Comment: I don't believe the isolation is of the insulation type, the transformer is an Intermatic PX50 and says "A grounded shield between the primary and secondary winding assures safe operation"

Comment: @aquaNoob That's an electrostatic shield. It in fact protects against single faults in the insulation between the shield and the windings. That shield is *not* directly connected to either the primary nor the secondary winding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformer output will be floating and the case earth bonded.

- Connect the lamp cable grounds to earth ground which may be for a shield or a metal fixture.
- The transformer insulation, protection, and GFCI will give good  protection

Comment: Ok, thanks, so I added a picture to the question, is this descriptive of your advice?

Comment: No it’s better as I did know there was an isolated ground on the unit